# How to know when a certain type of subspace of weakly holomorphic modular forms is non-trivial.

Tags: modular-forms

Given $N$, can we always find a non-constant weakly holomorphic modular form of level $N$ which is holomorphic at all cusps *except* possibly at $\infty$?

For example, $S_{4}(16)$ is $1$-dimensional so its generator is that non-constant (weakly) holomorphic modular form I'm looking for. On the other hand, $S_{3}(16)$ has dimension $0$. So what can I say about the space $S_{3}^{\#}(16) := \{f \in M^{!}_{3}(16) : f\text{ holomorphic at all cusps except possibly at } \infty\}$? That is, how do I know if it's non-trivial? Or how can I search for a non-constant element in such a space?

Comment: Which weight.. For even non-negative weight once again  : yes, this is Riemann-Roch theorem, $X=\Gamma \setminus \Bbb{H}^*$ is a compact Riemann surface, of genus $g$, $P=  i\infty$, for $n\ge g+1$, $L(nP)$ is [of dimension $\ge 2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_point), it contains a non-constant element $f$ and $(f')^{k/2}$ is weight $2k$ modular for $\Gamma$ and holomorphic on $\Bbb{H}$ and every cusp over than $i\infty$.

Comment: Once we have constructed any meromorphic form of odd weight (not sure how) it works the same way for odd weights.